# How to migrate mail data from one web host to another?

Tags: email, webserver, web-hosting

I want to migrate my website from lws to PlanetHoster but after looking closely at the files in the /mail directory, there are files that are named like:

```
5647726478.M4578658923475.web40.lws-hosting.com,S=5600647,W=545468:2,Rsc
1354956847.M6852558923475.web40.lws-hosting.com,S=8645647,W=978123:2,S
7568624549.M2364548486948.web40.lws-hosting.com,S=4792366,W=781215:2,Sc
```

And into PlanetHoster, they are named like:

```
5647726478.M4578658923475.web40.node9ca.n0c.com,S=5600647,W=545468:2,Rsa
1354956847.M6852558923475.web40.node9ca.n0c.com,S=8645647,W=978123:2,a
7568624549.M2364548486948.web40.node9ca.n0c.com,S=4792366,W=781215:2,Sa
```

So what do these namings mean? Why are the suffixes (Rsc, S, Sc) different from one to  another? Will it still work perfectly if I change `lws-hosting.com` to `node9ca.n0c.com` and nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Using maildir format](https://cr.yp.to/proto/maildir.html) and [Maildir Mailbox Format](https://doc.dovecot.org/admin_manual/mailbox_formats/maildir/).

For the migration i suggest [imapsync](https://github.com/imapsync/imapsync)